# Python-Robot framework - API automation - Getting error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'

Tags: python, api, automation, robotframework

Here is my code. I am getting error for this. Can anyone help

```
*** Settings ***

Library    RequestsLibrary
Library    JSONLibrary
Library    Collections

*** Variables ***
${base_url}     https://reqres.in
@{header}       Content-Type=application/json; charset=utf-8

*** Test Cases ***
POST_userInfo
    Create Session    mysession     ${base_url}
    ${body}=    Create Dictionary   name=Prad    job=leader

    ${response}=   POST On Session         mysession      api/users   data= ${body}   headers=@{header}
    Log To Console    ${response.status_code}
    Log To Console     ${response.content}
    Should Be Equal As Strings       ${response.status_code}  201
```

I am expecting POST request to sucess

Comment: I changed it but still see same issue

Answer (score 1):

The passed headers are expected to be a dictionary, while you are creating and passing a list object; hence the error, though a bit obscure *(being a python one)*, it says literally that.

If you want to define them in the Setting section, switch to this format:

```
&{header}       Content-Type=application/json    charset=utf-8
```

Note the prefix before the variable's name *(ampersand)*, and how the key=value pairs are separated with 2 or more spaces between them.